# Serialize XML file in AS3

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, xml-serialization, adobe

How can I serialize XML(meaning convert < to `&lt;` and > to `&gt;` etc...) using AS3. is there any build-in functionality or I have to use some regular expression to make global changes?

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the most simple way is using [`flash.xml::XMLNode`](https://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/xml/XMLNode.html) as follows:

```
    var xml:XML = <xml/>;
    xml.appendChild(new XMLNode(XMLNodeType.TEXT_NODE,"te<s>t"));
    trace(xml.toXMLString());//<xml>te&lt;s&gt;t</xml>
```

according to adobe `XMLNode` is only for legacy support, but I find it much more robust and simple than `XML`, although it doesn't support E4X.

The E4X approach is:

```
    var value:String = "te<s>t";
    var xml:XML = <xml>{value}</xml>;
    trace(xml.toXMLString());//<xml>te&lt;s&gt;t</xml>
```